# 404 on new installation using composer

Tags: installation

I have tried to install craft cms and I have been successful, in that I managed to go through the steps on cli and got a done message. The files are there, the database is populated. But when I go to my url.. Nothing.

I am installing at (https)tjob.be/dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of possible reasons why the frontend may not be working properly. If I have to guess, I'd say the server is probably configured wrong, pointing at the *project root* instead of the *web root*. The project root is the folder with your *composer.json* and *composer.lock* files, the web root is the folder with the `.htaccess` and `index.php` files (usually, this is the `web/` folder).

I recommend you set up a local development environment to get started and figure things out. This will allow you to debug more easily and find whatever is causing the 404 error without having to worry about what server settings might not be working properly.

Check out the guide on [local development](https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/environment/) to get started!

Comment: Thanks, I have not got a local environment set up and getting this set up on my web host has been challenging enough I feel. This is an addon domain of my main hosting account if that helps?

Comment: @tjcss It's way more painful to get a clean installation working on some remote hosting account where you don't have control over all the server settings. Check out the [recommended development environments](https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/environment/stack.html) here, there's a couple of tools there that don't take a lot of setup and are gonna be way easier to work with to develop your site.

Comment: Thanks @moritzLost. I have set up a local environment using Ddev